# Notch filtering minimizing artifacts in signal

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, artifacts

I have to notch filter the following signal.[image]

As you can see it is a signal with really high amplitude.And this causes me a lot of problems. I've designed a bandstop filter (46-55 Hz).The MATLAB code is

```
Fs=5000; sampling frequency

Wp_NOTCH = [36/(Fs/2) 71/(Fs/2)];
Ws_NOTCH= [46/(Fs/2) 55/(Fs/2)];
Rp_db=-20*log10(.95);
Rs_db=-20*log10(.05);
[order_NOTCH,wn_NOTCH] = buttord(Wp_NOTCH,Ws_NOTCH,Rp_db,Rs_db);
[B_NOTCH,A_NOTCH]=butter(order_NOTCH,wn_NOTCH,'stop');
```

And the filter is [image]
When i filter the signal (using filtfilt) I've the following signal[image] 
As you can see it has a lot of artifacts,and "waves". Is there a way to minimize these artifacts?How can I delete the 50Hz component minimizing these artifacts?Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to apply a notch filter? Your problem description is not clear at all. What should the signal look like? Have you looked at a frequency domain representation of your signal, such as the spectral densitiy?

Comment: I have to follow a protocol ,and I need to notch filter. Porco il tuo dio

Comment: In this case, I would advise you to just accept the result you already have. It is nonsensical but you will not get a better result using a notch filter. So you can at least stop wasting your time. Consider the protocol broken.

Comment: Using a median filter or a moving avarage filter sounds smart?It can smooth the high amplitude segment and it can delete the 50 hz component .

Answer (score 0):

Notch filters are designed to remove sine-waves with a set frequency, they cannot work for a sharp change in the data. The example you posted does not look like a 50Hz artifact, so notch filters cannot help here. You can look-up information on how to deal with data discontinuities, jump or step artifacts, or transient response. [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/examples/detecting-discontinuities-and-breakdown-points.html) is some explanation in matlab environment